# Access data on client from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Please actually read my post before placing it on hold!!

Let me start by saying I've been searching for a solution all afternoon and so far I have seen plenty of examples for WCF but none that would do what I need.

I have developed an application in c# that will be installed on customer servers and accesses a sql server on the customer's local network. The application also has the ability to control network relays on the customer's local network and records the status of these in sql. I am trying to figure out a way to have the customer's server establish a connection to our datacenter and be able to issue commands back to the customer's server (retrieve datasets from sql, control the network relays, etc). I have found plenty of ways to have a client call classes on a server but have so far been unsuccessful in finding the reverse. One consideration was writing a web service as part of the application on the customer's server but need a way to establish this connection for customers with dynamic IP addresses and without having to publish through firewalls, etc.

Comment: Have you considered using VPN?

Comment: Have you considered configuring a port redirect on the ADSL modem, and using a solution like www.noip.com ?

Comment: I have, however we are looking at hundreds to thousands of customers and don't want to have customers having to re-ip their network to use our software.  As far as noip or dyndns, we would rather not use these as then we would be publishing a web service through their modem.  I am really looking for a solution where in c# we open some kind of network stream back to our server that has an identity and we can in turn request data across, kind of like a logmein architecture where the service is just waiting.

Comment: Not too clear from your question, but it sounds a bit like you're just looking for [callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S2)?

Comment: I did some reading about callbacks but I didn't find a way to ask the client for data or to perform an action, only a way to push data back to the client.  Do you have an example of callbacks that would allow the server to request data from the client?

Comment: Could your data center keep a queue of tasks (such as "send dataset X" or "do something to network relay") that the client application will periodically poll for?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we need to be able to grab the data or send the device controls to the customer server in real time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to get information from the customer's database, which is behind a firewall and has no known static ip, in addition there might be several hundred customers so a dedicated VPN to the customer is not viable.

First of all: you should not contact the customer database directly. Databases are not designed for this scenario and would probably be left open to attack if exposed directly to the internet.
So you need a service on top of the database. There are two main options you can use for this service:

**Polling service**

The service is actually a client calling some web service on your network and asking for instructions.
*Benefits*: easy to implement and deploy.
*Downsides*: With polling there is always the cost-benefit of scalability/bandwidth use vs. speed of service. There are also some considerations in selecting the time to poll to prevent all the client polling at the same time.

**The service is a tcp-server**

This can be a usual web service (or RESTfull service) or some other service. The only difference is that it needs to advertise itself. For that you need to have a known directory server. When the service starts it then connects to the directory service and tells it the port it can be contacted on (the directory knows the ip from the connection). It will then need to periodically contact the directory to let it know it is still alive and so any change in IP is detected.
A client on your network would now query the directory to find the address of the client and connect directly to it to issue commands.

*Benefit*: Scalable and bandwidth efficient.
*Downside*: More difficult to implement. Requires firewall traversal solutions (UPNP or firewall exceptions).

Comment: This is exactly what we need.  Instead of having the application talk to a directory server to tell us where it is located, could we have it come back to our datacenter and establish a tcp stream to our server that we could then use to send requests back to the customer server?

Comment: That is the first option (Polling Server). A simple client application calls your server and asks for commands. You could then tell it what data to get. The problem is it would need to poll as it cannot know when you might want to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using

- **VPN** - Virtual private network

or

- Configuring a **Port Forwarding** redirect on the ADSL modem, and using a solution like www.noip.com ?

Comment: See reply to your comments above.

Comment: Oh, OK, given the scale, there is needed a better approach.